# jquery+php send values

Tags: php, jquery

i have forms createds that require a value , as this this forms edits different users.
so how would i send that value from jquery? i know how to do it with combobox , but i want to do it from links :

like - name [details] when someone clicks on details the forms will pop up, so i wana mimic index.php?id=2 but with jquery, anyideas?

Comment: Can you try and explain better. It is very hard to understand what you are after even after reading the questions twice.

Comment: sure, you know when you have a link in php that send  value and you get it with $_GET , well i wana do that but through jquery using dynamicly created text links. but i dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display some content via JQuery with a link? Modify the selector to point to the correct DOM object, eg. an anchor tag with class "details"

```
$('a .details').click(function ()
{
  $.get(
    'index.php?id=2',
    function(html)
    {
      $('#results').html(html);
    });
});
```

if you want to load the content the link is pointing to, use (untested)

```
$('a .details').click(function ()
{
  var anchor = this;
  $.get(
    $(anchor).attr('href'),
    function(html)
    {
      $('#results').html(html);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a .details').click(function ()

{  $.get(    'index.php?id=2', <--------------I need to pass that id=2 from a link thats created dynamicaly.    

function(html)   

 {      $('#results').html(html);    });});
```

for example, using 
a

```
<ul id="cat" >
</ul>
```

i can acces , "cat" through jquery, loop through the cat elements and each li id= 
will be clickable with some css

I cant figure out how to do it with normal text links!
thanks anyway dspinozzi

Answer (score 0):

if the id is stored in the li element, you can get the "id" attribute by using:

```
$('li').attr('id');
```